# Exception when passing params to another view controller

Tags: ios

Last night I let a project working. This morning the same project with no changes throws an exception at this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nuevo_servicio_segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"estoy en segue pasando a nuevo servicio");
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        NuevoServicioViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        //pasamos la latitud del PO
        //la convertimos a String
        NSString *latitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.latitude];
        vc.parametro_origin_latitude = latitud;
        //lo comprobamos
        NSLog(@"LATITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",latitud);
        //pasamos la lONGITUD del PO
        //la convertimos a String
        NSString *longitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.longitude];
        vc.parametro_origin_longitude = longitud;
        //lo comprobamos
        NSLog(@"LONGITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",longitud);

    }
}
```

The exception is at lines:

```
vc.parametro_origin_latitude = latitud;
```

and

```
vc.parametro_origin_longitude = longitud;
```

If I comment both lines the app doesn't crash, and I am completely sure that I haven't changed any piece of code.

I need your help to understand it.

EDITED:

Exception

```
2015-03-13 10:00:57.816 ABC[1358:29933] estoy en segue pasando a nuevo servicio
2015-03-13 10:00:57.816 ABC[1358:29933] -[UINavigationController setParametro_origin_latitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80ce83b0
2015-03-13 10:00:57.819 ABC[1358:29933] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setParametro_origin_latitude:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80ce83b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00c15946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0089ea97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00c1d5c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b663e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b65fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   ABC                             0x0005723d -[MainViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 445
    6   UIKit                               0x017f9b37 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 199
    7   UIKit                               0x0133681c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72
    8   ABC                             0x00056eb9 -[MainViewController boton_solicitar_action:] + 1001
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x008b47cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    10  UIKit                               0x011de23d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    11  UIKit                               0x011de1cf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    12  UIKit                               0x01311e86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    13  UIKit                               0x013122a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    14  UIKit                               0x0131150d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    15  UIKit                               0x0122e60a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    16  UIKit                               0x0122f0e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    17  UIKit                               0x011f4549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x0120437e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    19  UIKit                               0x011d8b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00b391df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00b2eced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00b2e248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00b2dbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00b2d9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02d9924f GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x02d9908c GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x011dc8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    28  ABC                             0x00066e5d main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0366dac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What exception did you get? Post the actual error message.

Comment: Both properties vc.parametro_origin_latitude and vc.parametro_origin_longitude are Strings?

Comment: @rdelmar, exception posted

Comment: @LoVo, yes. I will put the declarations in following comments

Comment: //origin_latitude
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *parametro_origin_latitude;

Comment: Your destination view controller is a navigation controller, not a NuevoServicioViewController as you think it is. You must have changed something in the storyboard to get this error. It couldn't have worked before if you didn't change anything.

Comment: //origin_longitude
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *parametro_origin_longitude

Comment: After posting your exception my question is obsolete ;)

Comment: @rdelmar, thank you, I am sure I haven't changed anything at the code, but I am not sure if I haven't changed anything in the storyboard. I will check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to set some values on a navigation controller that doesn't have those properties. The destination view controller of the segue must be a navigation controller, so you need to get its topViewController to access your custom controller.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nuevo_servicio_segue"])
        {
            NSLog(@"estoy en segue pasando a nuevo servicio");
            // Get reference to the destination view controller
            UINavigationController *nav= segue.destinationViewController;
            NuevoServicioViewController *vc = nav.topViewController;
            //pasamos la latitud del PO
            //la convertimos a String
            NSString *latitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.latitude];
            vc.parametro_origin_latitude = latitud;
            //lo comprobamos
            NSLog(@"LATITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",latitud);
            //pasamos la lONGITUD del PO
            //la convertimos a String
            NSString *longitud  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", self.puntoOrigen.longitude];
            vc.parametro_origin_longitude = longitud;
            //lo comprobamos
            NSLog(@"LONGITUD DEL PO PASADA=%@",longitud);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The segue comes from MainViewController, where the method is, and goes to the navigation controller that embeds NuevoServicioViewController.

Comment: I have removed the navigation controller and put the segue directly to the view controller, now it works, but I must say I don't remember embedding it with the navigation controller today :), thank you rdelmar

Comment: sure...thanks for your time and wisdom, you are always there to help